# API to access "Include values for this property in the search index" crawled property checkbox?

Tags: search

The CrawledProperty objects in Microsoft.Office.Sharepoint.Services.Administration doesn't seem to have any way of doing this...anyone know of a workaround?
I found a few postings on the net about this and the only post I've seen on MSDN is this:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/ff47669b-acf3-472f-9e5c-d577f5cf52c4/

Answer (score 3):

For me this works:

```
CrawledProperty.IsMappedToContents = true
CrawledProperty.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:
How to: Map a Crawled Property to a Managed Property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981343%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Creating and Exposing Managed Properties in the Advanced Search Page of SharePoint Server Enterprise Search
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428648%28v=office.12%29.aspx

(*NOTE*) These are for SharePoint 2007, but I used the article to do basically the same thing in 2010

Comment: Actually- Just noticed that you were looking for how to add "Include values for this property in the search index".  I believe the property you were looking for was:
PutInPropertyBlob =>
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.managedproperty.putinpropertyblob.aspx